# Having multiple gatling.conf files in a project

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have 2 Gatling performance test simulations where each require slightly different config values. I was wondering if it's possible to have a separate gatling.conf file for each simulation and if it is possible, how would I link them to the simulations (potentially some code in the IDEPathHelper)?

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/configuration/#gatling-conf)?

It's pretty explicit you have to use the `gatling.conf.file` System property.

Comment: ah missed that bit, cheers!